# Max R version of Machine Learning Server

Tags: r, sql-server, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

Having used [SQL Server Machine Learning Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/sql-server-machine-learning-services?view=sql-server-ver15) and realised that it only supports R up to version 3.5.2, I am exploring options to be able to deploy models for later versions of R. The experts (or more like sales people) at Microsoft told me about [Machine Learning Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/what-is-machine-learning-server). However, I am suspicious that it has similar issues as:

> R support is built on a legacy of Microsoft R Server 9.x and Revolution R Enterprise products.

I am pretty sure that this implies the same as above reg. the max R version (i.e. 3.5.2). Can someone confirm this please? I did many searches but could not find a definite answer.

I know this is looking for an opinion and people will vote for closure, but I reckon containerisation is the only way forward to avoid issues like the above?

Thanks!

PS:

I just installed Machine Learning Server version 9.4.7 as detailed here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/machine-learning-server/install/machine-learning-server-windows-install#howtoinstall

If I run:

```
R.Version()
```

I get:

$version.string
[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/sql-server-machine-learning-services?view=sql-server-ver15) "R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)"

I was told by Microsoft that it should be version 4.x. Maybe I am just thick. Can I upgrade to version 4.x.x and if so how please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can install a custom R runtime with SQL Server using Language Extensions. See [Install an R custom runtime for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/machine-learning/install/custom-runtime-r?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=platform-windows).